# Extra space when styling a table with CSS

Tags: html, css

As part of redesigning a site, I am trying to style a table with css.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

I ended up with this:

```
<table class="table1">

.table1 {
width: 100%;  
border: none;
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: colapse;
padding : 0;
}
```

The weird problem: when applying the css style to the table, the result is slightly different. The space between cells is slightly larger.

Please see the jsfiddles:

Table not style with css: http://jsfiddle.net/32534/1/
Table styled with css: http://jsfiddle.net/47AUR/1/

Why the extra space between the text inputs? What am I doing wrong?! Thank you!

Edit: Using Google Chrome.

Comment: I'm using chrome too and I can't see any substantial differences between the two tables

Comment: The nature of the tables with `width:100%` is it extends up to the parent container's end and set the columns width to be equal or auto. What you can do is, remove the `width:100%` from the table and set the width for each columns separately.

Comment: For better understanding, please check, http://jsfiddle.net/32534/4/

Comment: You have a typo: `colapse` should be `collapse`.

Comment: Thank you all! Great community on this site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cellpadding` affects `td` padding too, so simply add:

```
.table1 td{
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default chrome adds it's default styling:

```
`border-spacing: 2px;` on the table.
```

In http://jsfiddle.net/32534/1/ you haven't mentioned any styling for table. Hence it's picking up default style of chrome.

But in next fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/47AUR/1/ you have specifically mentioned the style for the table, which overwrites the default style of chrome.

It's a good idea to use **reset.css** to be consistent across all browser's and ignore the default styling of all browser's

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
td { 

padding: 0px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will work with a `padding:0` on the `td` (*as that is what the `cellpadding` affects*) elements and a second **l** to `colapse`

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/at4yL/